# Locate Command S option does not work

Tags: locate

I have installed the command (sudo apt install locate, sudo spt install mlocate) but the option s is not there. Cna somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is there for [compatibility](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html) for BSD systems so does nothing on non-BSD (for instance Linux).

```
-s, --stdio
          Accepted but does nothing, for compatibility with BSD
          locate.
```

> Cna somebody help me?

Not with the option. We use `>` for redirection so `locate this > save.txt` to create a text file with the results of `locate this`, For stdout and stderr we use `>&`